# How to pass 4 arraylist as input for httpurlconnection Get

Tags: android, mysql, arraylist, httpurlconnection, urlconnection

I have 4 list which is an input for a  mysql table. How can i pass these list paramerters in httpurlconnection  to get the JSON response. Below is my code. 
List1={"1","2"},List2={"50","60"},List3={"Type2","Type4"} and List4={"2015"}

```
             public static final String FetchURL = "http://xxxx.xxxx.com/fetchdesc.php";     
            new fetchDescInBackground().execute(FetchURL);
            URL url = new URL(params[0]);   
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            ArrayList<NameValuePair> dataToSend1 = new ArrayList<>(params[0]);
            ArrayList<NameValuePair> dataToSend2 = new ArrayList<>(params[1]);
             ArrayList<NameValuePair> dataToSend3 = new ArrayList<>(params[2]);    
              ArrayList<NameValuePair> dataToSend4 = new ArrayList<>(params[3]);
       InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
       InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
       BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
       StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(); 
       String tempstring;

              while ((tempstring = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                  stringBuilder.append(tempstring);
                stringBuilder.append("\n");
                }
```

How can i pass the 4 list as an input to mysql? There is only one table where the values are input for the columns in table. Please help.

Comment: use volley and return your data as hash map in getParams() overriden method. [here](https://github.com/DWorkS/VolleyPlus) is the link

Comment: Please help me with AsyncTask as i am not using Volley.

Answer (score 0):

Hav a look on this code :

```
URL url = new URL("http://yoururl.com");
HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setRequestMethod("GET");


List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("firstParam", paramValue1));
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("secondParam", paramValue2));
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("thirdParam", paramValue3));

OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
        new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
writer.write(getQuery(params));
writer.flush();
writer.close();
os.close();

conn.connect();
```

Use this according to your input parameter requirements

Comment: for 1 list i am aware how about more than 1 list which i am having values already. I need to use GET for fetching values based on user input. thanks for your reply

Comment: okay just merge all lists into one ....and bind it to url.  To merge multiple lists like this :=> list_var.addAll(list_var2) and repeat it untill you get one list with all parameters

Comment: Those 4 values are input to mysql table, if i merge how can i split there in php?

Comment: can't you duplicate those list var's one group for input in mysql and another as url param ?

Comment: Query which going to use is "Select * from table where List1 IN(list1 values from android),List2 IN(List2 values from android)....List3 & List4". If i merge those values on receiving end what basis i can split.? hope this helps. Please help me sending this values separately.

Comment: Apologies for late response...Use Map instead of List.